# Python Pandas, check the condition of certain columns in a row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
      var1  var2  var3  var4
Id#                         
1001     Y     Y     Y     Y
1002     N     N     N     N
1003     N     N     Y     N
1003     Y     Y     Y     N
```

I want to create a new column called Small, where if any var=Y then Small is equal to N

```
      var1  var2  var3  var4  Small
Id#                         
1001     Y     Y     Y     Y      N       
1002     N     N     N     N      Y 
1003     N     N     Y     N      N
1003     Y     Y     Y     N      N
```

My tried solution:
I have created a function called is_small that flips to 'N' anytime there a column in a row is 'Y'

```
def is_small(row, *cols):
    _small = 'Y'
    for col in cols:
        if col == 'Y':
            _small = 'N'
    return _small
```

and apply it to my dataset:

```
all_data['Small'] = all_data.apply(lambda row: is_small(row,
                                                        'var1',
                                                        'var2',
                                                        'var3',
                                                        'var4'),
                                   axis=1)
```

However Small just all return as 'Y' and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. but every time you pass literal 'var1', 'var2'... into `is_small`, that's why it always return 'Y'. You should pass `row['var1']`,  `row['var2']`....

```
all_data['Small'] = all_data.apply(lambda row: is_small(row,
    row['var1'],
    row['var2'],
    row['var3'],
    row['var4']),
axis=1)
```

Comment: So what I was doing was passing my function the list of *args `['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where` (*vectorized if/else*):

```
df['small'] = pd.np.where(df.eq('Y').any(1), 'N', 'Y')

df
#    var1 var2  var3  var4  small
#Id                 
#1001   Y    Y     Y    Y   N
#1002   N    N     N    N   Y
#1003   N    N     Y    N   N
#1003   Y    Y     Y    N   N
```

Comment: I have other columns besides var1, var2, var3, var4., that may have Y/N responses.

Comment: You can select these four columns manually before constructing the boolean condition if that is the case. `pd.np.where(df[['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']].eq('Y').any(1), 'N', 'Y')`